# SCP transfer a file from localhost to a sftp server through php script

Tags: php, passwords, sftp, scp

Hi Trying to send a file to another server using scp.. cannot use sftp as it is not installed on my server so i am getting a function not found for ssh2_connect.

So my only option as i can see it is scp.
Now the problem come with i cannot include my password in the php scp script.

ie:

```
scp filename username:passwor@server:filename
```

It gives me the error that the server username doesn't exist
If i use it without the password

```
scp filename username@server:filename
```

it prompts me for password

PS: I am testing the script in a command line on the localhost first as to get the error messages.

Any advice?

TA

Comment: what about use scp without the need of insert password like http://www.notesbit.com/index.php/scripts-unix/linux-how-to-use-the-scp-secure-copy-command-without-passwords/

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use the SFTP binaries you could use phpseclib - a pure-PHP SFTP implementation:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Kevin, if you don't have the PHP SSH2 extension installed on your server then your best bet is to setup public/private key authentication on your other server if you have access. Then you can keep the private key on your PHP server, and pass -i  on your scp command, something like this:

`scp -i /var/www/htdocs/myphpproject/rsakey filename username@server:filename`